Truncate text in a MudTable cell
How can I instruct a MudTable to truncate text in a cell instead of allowing the text to wrap onto the next line?
Here is a code sample
<MudTable Items="@data">
    <ColGroup>
        <col style="width: 80%" />
        <col style="width: 20%" />
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Description</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd>@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd>@context.Description</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

@code {
    public string Text { get; set; } = "????";
    public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Click Me";
    public int ButtonClicked { get; set; }

    public class TableStructure
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    private List<TableStructure> data = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        data.Add(new() { Name = "Name1", Description = "Description 1"});
        data.Add(new() { Name = "Name2", Description = "Description 2"});
        data.Add(new() { Name = "Name3", Description = "Description 3"});
        data.Add(new() { Name = "Name4", Description = "Description 4 - This is a really long description that is the problem"});
    }

}

How do I convert the description for the final item from the wrapped text to something like " Description 4 - this is......."
I've found css that allows word breaks but nothing that supports truncating.
Any ideas?  Is there something I can add at a project level that each table can inherit?
Here is a playground
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkmSaevAnmAsvCEE

You can style the <MudTd> element to achieve this.
<MudTable Items="@data">
    <ColGroup>
        <col style="width: 80%" />
        <col style="width: 20%" />
    </ColGroup>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Description</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd>@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd Style="max-width: 1px;overflow-wrap: break-word;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;">@context.Description</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

These are the css styles you need to completely ignore the text if it overflows.
Note: max-width needs to be >= 0.
{
    max-width: 1px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Or, if you want the cell to be scrollable instead then:-
overflow-y: hidden;
// or 
overflow: auto;

Demo MudBlazor Snippet

Excellent - that is exactly what I wanted.  Is there a way I can amend the CSS style to affect every table I have in my project?  Thanks for the answer.  Amazing.

You can override the css class with the styles for MudTh which MudBlazor adds. Either use browser tools or look at their repo to find out what classes are applied.

 In case anyone is looking for how to make it global
You can check the length of the description and display a substring.
<RowTemplate>
    <MudTd>@context.Name</MudTd>
    <MudTd>
        @if(context.Description.Length > 5)
        {
            @($"{context.Description.Substring(0, 5)}...")
        }
        else
        {
            @context.Description
        }
    </MudTd>
</RowTemplate>


Thanks this works but I need to consider how big the cell is on the screen to maximise the number of characters displayed.  Thanks for the suggestion.
